# fatal error: occi.h: No such file or directory | fedora 20

Tags: c++, oracle, gcc, fedora

When I try to make a C++ program, compilation terminated by throwing following error

```
Invoking: GCC C++ Compiler
g++ -I/usr/include/oracle/12.1/client64 -I/usr/include/log4cpp -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -MMD -MP -MF"src/xmlHandler/xmlReader.d" -MT"src/xmlHandler/xmlReader.o" -o "src/xmlHandler/xmlReader.o" "../src/xmlHandler/xmlReader.cpp"
In file included from ../src/xmlHandler/../util/UtilMethods.h:18:0,
                 from ../src/xmlHandler/xmlReader.cpp:25:
../src/xmlHandler/../util/SessionManager.h:8:18: fatal error: occi.h: No such file or directory
 #include <occi.h>
                  ^
compilation terminated.
```

What could be the problem here and how to solve this ? (oracle and gcc installed already!)

Thanks!

Comment: You should not really used Fedora 20, since it is years after EOL and can contain serious security vulnerabilities.

Answer (score 0):

Wich oracle client do you have installed? Instant client? If instant - so, you need to install "Instant Client Package - SDK" too (it contains C header files).